# How to know the Path of a File inside a recursive directory structure

Tags: linux

I am using Linux server through putty tool .
Inside the linux server , I entered into a folder which is a  Web Application (This  is consisting of a number of sub directories with in it ) 
Inside that directory I need to find out a path of a java file where it is residing .

I tried using

ls -LR HttpXmlClient.java

( As i want to know the path of HttpXmlClient.java  ) where it is residing exactly ??

Please let me know , thank you very much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find command:

```
find $PWD -name 'HttpXmlClient.java'
```

Comment: Note that in general, the `$PWD` shell variable and the `/bin/pwd` command may give different output if the shell traversed symbolic links. `$PWD` will represent the path that the shell took, including symbolic links, whereas `/bin/pwd` walks the parent directory links to find the path without symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

The pwd command is what you are looking for.